# Large number of snapshots on a ZFS system

Tags: backup, solaris, zfs, snapshot

Here's my scenario: I have two servers (well many more, but two for this scenario), one is a Solaris backup server, the second is a CentOS Linux Server. Every night the CentOS server runs a cron job to rsync itself to the Solaris backup server. After this is done, it puts the date and time into a special file on the Solaris server. The Solaris server has a cron job run every minute and if it sees this file, it grabs the contents and uses that to make a snapshot.

The result is great: Every day the backup automatically runs and then creates a ZFS snapshot. Been working great for over two months. I had expected that by now I would be low on space and would need to start (manually) deleting old snapshots. But in fact, I am fine on space. My only concern is, with 60+ snapshots and more being added daily, are there any known problems with large numbers of ZFS snapshots? Is there a maximum number of ZFS snapshots a ZFS filesystem can have? Or am I OK to just keep accumulating snapshots until I am low on space?

Comment: Note that after asking this I opted for a lot of snapshots using `cron`, and after 10 years and 42,000+ snapshots later I discovered that there's [a definite space impact](https://serverfault.com/questions/1057059/are-zfs-snapshots-really-free) even though performance was still fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [no problem with lots of snapshots](http://web.archive.org/web/20120211211239/http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/zfs-discuss/2009-March/027191.html). Having thousands of ZFS filesystems can cause boot times of more than an hour, but you're not doing that.

Comment: unfortunately oracle have helpfully broken all their links so this answer is not very useful anymore

Comment: @JamesRyan Fortunately the internet archive saved a copy, so I've updated the link in my answer.

Comment: What do you think of creating a snapshot on every file change? Disregard temporary files or stuff in RAMFS/TMPFS.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't be too concerned about this.  You're talking about 1 snapshot a day here.  I have heard of production environments with over 10k snapshots.  But I don't have any information on how this was working for them but I didn't hear it in a bad context so I'm going to assume that it was working well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wish I could have accepted both your answer as well as TRS-80's answer... But your was almost equally as helpful!